# EC2 AWS Amazon: Stopping an instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to understand something related to EC2.

I read in the user guide that's provided by Amazon that if i move my instance to "stopped" state then i'm not going to be charged for additional instance hours while the instance is in a stopped state. - and that's understandable.

But what happens for example if I transform the state from "stopped" state to "running" state 4 times in a single hour? 
Will I be charged for 4 hours or just for 1 hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have any provisioned EBS volumes. You will still get charged for those since they are still provisioned regardless of whether or not the instance is running.
2. If you start and stop 4 times in an hour, you will be billed for 4 hours. In such a case, its better to keep the instance running for almost an hour.